# Iterating over views in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I am trying to resize all NSTextFields in an NSTableView that is view based. I want to call [myTextfield sizeToFit] on all textfields. My question is how to iterate over all views in my tableview. I tried enumerateAvailableRowViewsUsingBlock: but it doesn't work. What can i do to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  In IB set the Tag of your text field to whatever you'd like (in this example I'm using 1).  You will then be able to access the `NSTableCellView` for each row by calling `viewAtColumn:row:makeIfNecessary:`.  Make sure `makeIfNecessary:` is set to `YES`.

Code:

```
int x;
for (x = 0; x < [tableView numberOfRows]; x++) {
    NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:x makeIfNecessary:YES];
    NSTextField *tField = [cellView viewWithTag:1];
    [tField sizeToFit];
}
```

This worked for me so I would be surprised if it doesn't for you.  If anyone could give some insight on why `makeIfNecessary:` has to be `YES` to access a row view that should already be created I would appreciate it.

Comment: Ditto your question on makeIfNecessary:, sud0.  Testing my app, if I set it to NO, the method returned nil in 5 out of 10 test runs.  But if I set it to YES,

Comment: continuing, if I set it to YES, it returns a view as expected in 25/25 test runs.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the total number of rows by `int numberOfRows = [yourTableView numberOfRows]`. Then use that to iterate over them and call your method. (Assuming that you gave your NSTextField a unique **tag** in IB to distinguish it from other subviews of your NSTableCellView).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
        NSTableCellView *someTableCellView = [[yourTableView viewAtColumn:(NSInteger) row:i makeIfNecessary:FALSE];
        NSTextField *yourTextField = [someTableCellView viewWithTag:(NSInteger)];
    }
```

Another place to do it is in the NSTalbeView delegate method `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` which is invoked everytime you call `reloadData` on your tableView.

Comment: Thanks @bijan, but this solution didn't work for me. When i print the view via NSLog() it refers to null.

Comment: Which one refers to null, NSTableCellView or NSTextField?

Comment: The NSTableCellView (my subclass from it).

Comment: When i try to do this in tableView:viewForColumn:row i am able to call [mytextfield sizeToFit] but the problem is i can't determine which textfield in my table has the maximum width.